# Need some guidance on creating this photon torpedo

Tags: particles

Need some help to make a photon torpedo from Star Trek, as the one attached.

I know how to make the sphere object titillate and change colors.
I tried doing an emitter and attaching picture to make the beams but it looked choppy.

How can I make and make and animate the "beams" that surround the torpedo?

[image: Photon Torpedo]

[image: Almost there]

Comment: You can always use compositing. Getting the torpedo on its own layer with any occluders as masks shouldn’t be too hard. You can use a glare node to get some beams probably, and with some animation for frame number usage, it could work.

Comment: seems more a work for a post-prod soft like After Effects

Comment: Is this for Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: @Blunder I am open to doing it in either. Whichever gets the best look. I realize there is some compositing work, I am just not sure how to go about it. Especially with the beams/rays.

Answer (score 4):

The beam effect of the "photon torpedo" (or "magic missile"/"wisp") can be created on the base of a [fake light cone](https://youtu.be/hTbXFH1a4BM), that is turned into a "[billboard](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54871/what-is-billboarding-and-can-should-it-be-used-in-3d-games-to-create-special-ef)" which always points to the camera. A *Displacement* modifier animates the beams.

Example animation (Cycles, 10 samples):
[image: example animation]

Known issues:

- In Eevee, it works in a dark environment when you set *Settings > Blend Mode* to `Alpha Blend` on the *Material Properties* tab. Depending on the shader for the halo effect and in a bright environment/room try `Alpha Hashed`. But this will cause a lot of noise in Eevee. Probably because Eevee can't handle transparent emissions not very well. Increasing the sample count to 256 and the *Denoise* node in *Compositor* helps a bit.
- the photon does not work well as a particle instance (rendered as a whole collection) because all *Displacement* modifiers use the same *Empty*. So the beams look all the same for a given frame. To randomize this more a *Geometry Nodes* modifier might be a good choice (not tested).

The photon model is a half-sphere with "a tail" of 2 cones. Select the bottom vertices of the inner cone and outer cone and add each group to a vertex group (*Displaced* in the example). Use this group for the *Displacement* modifiers. The built-in *Clouds* texture was used for the modifiers. The *Displacement* modifier of the outer cone has a very low *Strength* (0.1). The inner cone has a high *Strength* value (2.8, see screenshot).

A moving *Empty* object generates the noise/animation for the modifiers.

[image: photon model]

Make both cones a child of the photon sphere. Then add a *Damp Track* object constraint to it and select the camera as the *Target*. Try `-Z` or `Z` for the *Track Axis* to make it always point to the camera. Depending on the size of the halo effect, it may look better one way or another.

[image: screenshot 2]

The inner cone has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth the result of the displacement. (The *Solidify* modifier was just a test.)

Shader (Cone Inner, Beams):
[image: cone inner]

Shader (Cone Outer, Halo):
[image: cone outer]

Shader (Photon, center):
[image: shader photon]

Comment: I feel like I am almost there, however, I think I am missing a detail/step on how to get the right position of the materials. I uploaded a screenshot of what I have.

Comment: I can upload an example if you want to have a look. I've tested a Geometry Nodes modifier as a replacement for the Displacement modifier. It works partly. You can have unique torpedos but the Damp Track constraint is messed up. Maybe the torpedos need to be fired with GN, too.

Comment: Id greatly appreciate it if you could! Or if it is possible here to upload the blend file, I would look to take a look at it and compare/learn.

Comment: Do you think I could get that torpedo model but in orange like normal ones. I'm making a game it would be helpful. Thanks discord is iroge #0502

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to upload the blend file :-/ I think I still have it somewhere and can add it...